# How to strip out links from website to a text file in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

is there an equivalent under windows command to :

`grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' file`

The idea is to grab all links directly from a website to a text file.
and those links have a common prefix `http://download.` and suffix `/file`

Regards.

Comment: I tried all combinations with **findstr /r**, but the result is the whole table row <tr>, the question now would be: how obtain the clean URL only§

Comment: I've used **xidel 2.txt -e '(//@href, //@src)/resolve-uri(.)'** , but how to filter urls begining with **http://download.** and ending with **/file**?

Comment: Is the use of windows batch a requirement or just for exercise? If the later, you should probably use other options, which are available on any recent Windows installation out of the box, like VB Script, Powershell, etc.

Comment: I used batch, just because i am familiar with it, other solutions are welcome

Comment: Other solution is to install cygwin or some other set of unix tools and use the grep command you wrote in your question.

Comment: thank you!, this is the final solution for a lazy person like me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a possibility to install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) or some other shell for Windows? In that case you could use grep and other useful tools.

Windows has [findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) (run findstr /? for help) and find.

Comment: I've tried **findstr /R "(.*download.*file)" c:\users\user\desktop\2.txt** but there is no output, while the 2.txt file contains the links as the pattern